# После перехода по ссылке на другую страницу нужно, чтобы в select был выбран определенный option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<!--Страница, на которой есть ссылки-->
<ul>
  <li><a id=1 href="/include/index1.php"></a></li>
</ul>

<!--Страница "index1.php", на которой есть select-->
<select>
  <option id=1>Apple</option>
  <option id=2>Orange</option>
  <option id=3>Juice</option>
</select>
```

И должен быть реализовано так, чтобы при клике по ссылке с id=1, на другой странице был выбран option с id=3

Comment: традиционно для этих целей используются get-параметры, а-ля `href="index.php?id=3"`, а тот скрипт берет его из `$_GET['id']` и в цикле вывода списка делает что-то вида `$selected = ($x == $_GET['id']) ? "selected" : "";` и потом `<?= "<option value=".." $selected"></option>`

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать и без PHP. Ссылку в первом файле переписать так:

```
<a href="/include/index1.php?1"></a>
```

а во втором файле добавить такой JS-код:

```
if(location.search.substring(1) == "1") document.getElementById("3").selected = true;
```

Comment: Только лучше по нормальному параметры передавать, типо `?select=1`

Comment: Согласен, но так будет чуть сложнее его получать на принимающей стороне. JS придётся переписать так: `if(location.search.substring(1).split("=")[1] == "1") document.getElementById("3").selected = true;`

Comment: Или попробовать [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/7692602)

Comment: Тогда опять переписывать: `if(new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("select") == "1") document.getElementById("3").selected = true;`